# Dynamically Registering and unregistering broadcast from a non activity class

Tags: android

I have a class which has the following definition:

```
public final class BluetoothDevicePreference extends Preference implements
    CachedBluetoothDevice.Callback, OnClickListener
```

I need to register and unregister a broadcast from this class.

Since this being a preference class and not an activity/PreferenceActivity, where should I do the registering and unregistering of my broadcast?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the broadcast for?  When do you want it listening for broadcasts?

Answer (score 1):

`context.registerReceiver(receiver);` and `context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)`

Comment: where? in which overriden methods of Preference?